# Jmeter graph interpretation

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am very new at Jmeter and am trying to get an idea of how to interprete the graphs below. The test i performed used 1 thread group with 3600 user ramped up ever .1 seconds. 2 images are attached to this question to better explain myself. The first shows the summary of the test and the second shows the average response time.  As I said I am super green at this and would just like some insight on how to interprate these graphs.  Since there are no huge spikes does this mean the server/website can handle this load without issue?  What would a graph look like if the server was not able the handle the load?   Also, is 3600 user count with .1 second rampup the best way to try to put load on the site? thank you for all your guidance

Test Summary number image:

[image]

Average Response graph image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

90% of response times above 40 seconds is a little bit high for me. If it is "normal" web application - no one will wait for 40 seconds for the page to load. Moreover it seems you test has some errors like [4xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) and [5xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) HTTP response codes and even non-HTTP responses

Also you report is missing some major points like:

1. Total number of errors and percentage compared to all executed tests. If it something like statistical noise it can be ignored, but even 1 percent of 100k transactions is 1000 failed requests
2. There is no information about cause of the errors, i.e. what is the bottleneck. You should be also measuring main health metrics on application under test side like CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk, Network usage as well as application and database-specific metrics if any. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for details.
3. There is no information about virtual users so you cannot correlate the increasing load with the other metrics.
4. 1 second ramp-up is not the best way to simulate the load on your server as initially you should be adding more virtual users gradually in order to see how does your application behave when more and more virtual users arrive. So given your scenario you can say something like: "my application cannot handle 3600 users, response time is very high and there are errors", but you don't know how many users can be handled, when response time starts exceeding reasonable thresholds, and why. Your test is something like [Stress Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) which is also important, but normally people start with the load testing when anticipated load is being simulated.